# GUI with methods

Tags: c#, methods

I took this code from my console application and I am trying to make it work with a GUI. Am I not calling the methods right or what? I want to click the OK button and display the sum, difference, and product of the numbers separately on 3 labels. Confused. Please help.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Numbers2GUI
    {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num1 = 5;
        int num2 = 3;

        Sum(num1, num2);
        Difference(num1, num2);
        Product(num1, num2);

    }

    public static void Sum(int num1, int num2)

    {
        addLabel.Text = ("The sum of the numbers is {0}.", num1 + num2);
    }

    public static void Difference(int num1, int num2)
    {
        differenceLabel.Text = ("The difference of the numbers is {0}.", num1 - num2);
    }
    public static void Product(int num1, int num2)
    {
        double multiply = num1 * num2;
        productLabel.Text = ("The product of the numbers is {0}.", multiply);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It looks like you want to call `string.Format`, but you're not actually doing that. Try `addLabel.Text = string.Format("The sum of the numbers is {0}.", num1 + num2);`

Comment: Also, we can guess what's wrong from your code, but it's **much** easier if you put the actual error message, or describe what's wrong in detail!

Comment: That string fixed most errors. But now I get - An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Numbers2GUI.Form1.addLabel

Comment: None of those `static` methods should be static - remove the `static` keyword on all three.

Comment: That did the trick, been looking at code too much tonight. Thanks a million my friend.

Answer (score 3):

I see two big problems:

1. Use the [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method to format the result in the labels.
2. If you want to update elements on the form, your `Sum`, `Difference`, and `Product` methods should *not* be declared as `static`.

Try this:

```
public void Sum(int num1, int num2)
{
    addLabel.Text = string.Format("The sum of the numbers is {0}.", num1 + num2);
}

public void Difference(int num1, int num2)
{
    differenceLabel.Text = string.Format("The difference of the numbers is {0}.", num1 - num2);
}

public void Product(int num1, int num2)
{
    double multiply = num1 * num2;
    productLabel.Text = string.Format("The product of the numbers is {0}.", multiply);
}
```

Comment: This error remains for all 3 .text values.                                       An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Numbers2GUI.Form1.addLabel'

Comment: Notice my second point, "your methods shouldn't be static". remove the `static` keyword from `Sum`, `Difference`, and `Product`.

Comment: Was too quick to try the first part of the solution and I overlooked your other half. Sorry. That did the trick, been looking at code too much tonight. Thanks a million my friend.